# jquery hidden box scripts don't work in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, explorer

I am not an advanced jquery programmer. Just started my adventure with it. I faced a serious problem. The script which I created doesn't work in IE. It works in firefox and chrome. Could you please help me with this?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#quotein')
        .css('margin-left', '-890px');

    var paddingLeft = parseInt($('#quotein .quote1').css('padding-left'));
        console.log(paddingLeft);
    var paddingRight = parseInt($('#quotein .quote1').css('padding-right'));
    var slideWidth = $('#quotein .quote1').width() + paddingLeft+paddingRight;
    slideWidth = ''+slideWidth+'px';

    var isHidden = false;

    $('#quotein .quotebutton')
        .css('cursor', 'pointer')
        .click(function(){
            if(!isHidden){
                isHidden = true;
                $(this)
                    .css('background', 'url(_images/generic/quote-out.png) no-repeat left') 
                    .parent()
                    .animate({
                        'left': slideWidth
                    }, 'fast');
            }else{
                isHidden = false;
                $(this)
                    .css('background', 'url(_images/generic/quote-in.png) no-repeat left')
                    .parent()
                    .animate({
                        'left': '0px'
                    }, 'fast');
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't very specific.  Is there an error?  What is that error?  If the behavior is different, explain what the behavior _is_ and _how_ it is different.  When you debug it, on what line of code does the problem start?

Comment: Comment the console.log line, sometimes IE throws an error when you don't have developer tools opened and trying to write to the console.

Comment: I have commented the console.log line and its working fine. thank you @slash197.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Comment the console.log line, sometimes IE throws an error when you don't have developer tools opened and trying to write to the console. – slash197 Jul 9 at 10:34

This was causing a problem. Thanks @slash197.